# Pass array to constructor in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am fiddling with this issue and cannot resolve it - just wanted to check if anyone here can help with tips

I am loading the class and calling the constructor like this

```
include_once './Myaws.php';
$aws = new Myaws();
$aws->bucket = $images['config']['bucket'];
```

Myaws.php is as follows

```
class Myaws {

    public $bucket;    

    function __construct() {        
        $this->aws = Aws::factory('./config/aws_config.php');
    }

}
```

It works like a charm!

**Now the issue**

The './config/aws_config.php' is just an array that will change depending on the deployment stage - so I want to make it dynamic. Here is what I do and it doesnt work

```
include_once './Myaws.php';
$aws = new Myaws();
$aws->bucket = $images['config']['bucket'];
$aws->config = $images['config']['awsconfig'];
```

And in the Myaws.php, I change the following

```
class Myaws {

    public $bucket;    
    public $config;    

    function __construct() {        
        $this->aws = Aws::factory($this->config);
    }

}
```

It doesn't work :( and neither does the below one

```
include_once './Myaws.php';
$aws = new Myaws($images['config']['awsconfig']);
$aws->bucket = $images['config']['bucket'];

class Myaws {

    public $bucket;    

    function __construct($config) {        
        $this->aws = Aws::factory($config);
    }

}
```

This is pretty basic Oops and I don't seem to get it I think. Can anyone suggest me how can I make that variable $config dynamic?

Comment: Does 'images' refer to an AMI? print_r($config) and make sure you're passing what you think you are. Also might need to elaborate on 'doesn't work'

Comment: I see no reason why your last example wouldn't work. Does PHP or the `Aws` class trigger any errors?

Comment: Basically, Aws::factory('./config/aws_config.php') takes an array as input and if I input an array directly it works, if I put as a config file it works but it doesnt if I do it in the way I showed you folks.

Comment: The AWS class gives a missing security credentials error showing that the passed value never reaches. Images is just an array... I shall still dig in more...

Answer (score 3):

I found the formatting on the included file vs in a passed array to be not 100% compatible.  Also check the in the api docs how they use my_profile to pass those credentials.

here is a example of the current method I am using to generation the config

```
$aws = Aws::factory($this->getAwsConfig());


   private function getAwsConfig()
{
    return array(
        // Bootstrap the configuration file with AWS specific features
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => $this->awsKey,
            'secret' => $this->awsSecret
        ),
        'includes' => array('_aws'),
        'services' => array(
            // All AWS clients extend from 'default_settings'. Here we are
            // overriding 'default_settings' with our default credentials and
            // providing a default region setting.
            'default_settings' => array(
                'params' => array(
                    'region' => $this->awsRegion
                )
            )
        )
    );

}
```